# A correct way to include Google Maps library in Rails app to pass Google PageSpeed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, asset-pipeline

Here is a way how I include assets now (at the bottom of body tag).

```
= javascript_include_tag 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'
= javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

But when I try to pass Google PageSpeed test I got this
[image]

As I understand, I need to use `async` attribute for script tag. But when I trying to do this, it breaks all logic flow in js files.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you wan't to reduce the number of block rendering script you could do the following:

- use [Google Fonts Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) to load your fonts asynchronous
- load [Google maps asynchronous](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async)

For Google Font Loader you will add this inside your header:

```
  WebFontConfig = {
    google: {
      families: ['Roboto:300,400,500,700:latin']
    }
  };

  (function() {
    var wf = document.createElement('script');
    wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') + '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.6/webfont.js';
    wf.type = 'text/javascript';
    wf.async = 'true';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
  })();
```

If you don't want to request the file from Google you can add the file from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.6/webfont.js to your assets and load it from there (but I recommend sticking with Google). Have a look at the documentation to learn what to do after you load your fonts using the loader (You must modify a little your css - but only few lines).

For Google maps use the code from their example.
One little suggestion here would be to load the script using the exact function used to load the web fonts.